# How to prevent If statement from converting input to Boolean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the user input value from the function (`enter_student_name`) and add it into my dictionary function (`add_student`). But when I print, I get a Boolean value instead of the string that was entered.

---

Console Example: Enter student name: **`john`**

```
[{'name': True}]
```

---

I want it to return `[{'name': john}]` instead.

```
students = []

def enter_student_name():
    while True:
        student_name = str.isalpha(input('Enter student name: '))

        if student_name:
        add_student(student_name)
        print(students)
        # enter_student_id()
    else:
        print('Please enter a name only')
        continue


def add_student(name):
    student = {"name": name }
    students.append(student)
```

Comment: The `if` has absolutely nothing to do with it, its the `.isalpha()` that's turning your string into a boolean.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

`str.isalpha()` returns true or false if the string is alpha characters. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm

Instead get the value from input, THEN check for alpha characters:

```
students = []


def enter_student_name():
    while True:
        student_name = input('Enter student name: ')

        if str.isalpha(student_name):
            add_student(student_name)
            print(students)
            # enter_student_id()
        else:
            print('Please enter a name only')
            continue


def add_student(name):
    student = {"name": name }
    students.append(student)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `isalpha()` to the if statement:

```
    student_name = input('Enter student name: ')

    if student_name.isalpha():
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str` instead of `str.isalpha`, so instead of:

```
str.isalpha(input('Enter student name: '))
```

use

```
str(input('Enter student name: '))
```

this will convert any given value to string and make it work.

then use an if condition with the `isalpha` to check whether if the string contains all letters before making it call the `add_student(student_name)` function call.